# blocked third party cookies on google chrome but i can still see the 3p cookies being set

Tags: google-chrome, cookies, google-chrome-devtools

I've disabled third party cookies on google chrome but i can still see the cookies being set in the DevTools application tab.

1. I loaded a web page, it led to cookies being set for various domains.
2. Then i deleted only the cookies of a one third party domain.
3. Then i blocked third-party cookies in chrome settings.
4. Then refreshed the page.
5. I see the cookies of that third party domain that i'd deleted being set again.
6. Can anyone point out if this is expected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disabling third party cookies only disables their **installation**.
Cookies that already exist are not deleted.

You may delete all cookies in Chrome, but beware, since this will most likely
invalidate some of your stored logins.

For more information see the Google article
[Clear, enable, and manage cookies in Chrome](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95647?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en).

Comment: 1. I loaded a web page, it led to cookies being set for various domains. 
2. Then i deleted only the cookies of a one third party domain. 
3. Then i blocked third-party cookies in chrome settings.
4. Then refreshed the page.
5. I see the cookies of that third party domain that i'd deleted being set again.
6. Is this expected?

Comment: Might require restart of Chrome.

Comment: i just restarted chrome and tested again. Same thing. I'm using chrome version 68. Tested the same thing on chrome 62, this issue is not coming. 3p cookies are not getting set again.

Comment: I tried on a separate machine with chrome 69, this issue is not happening there. Will update chrome on my machine and test again.

Comment: The issue is not happening for chrome 69. Thanks!